# Definition of genotype in demuxlet

Tags: single-cell, genotyping, demultiplexing

I am reading the Online methods of the [demuxlet paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nbt.4042).

The genotype $g$ is taken from the set $\{0, 1, 2\}$, defined as "the true genotype of the sample corresponding to $c$-th droplet at $v$-th variant".
What is the mapping between these values and the corresponding genotype?

Each variant is modeled using a binomial with $n=2,p=\frac{g}{2}$, so I would assume that 1 is heterozygous, 0 is homozygous REF and 2 homozygous ALT. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The genotypes $\{0,1,2\}$ are mappings to the genotypes AA (homref), AB (heterozygous), BB (homalt) (from [supplementary](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fnbt.4042/MediaObjects/41587_2018_BFnbt4042_MOESM6_ESM.pdf) resources). This is also mapped to the number of alterations (e.g., 0 -> 0 alterations -> homref).